# Extracting a single layer from a SHP file

Tags: graphics, import

I have an ESRI ShapeFile (SHP) that I've loaded.  It has a number of layers which I can see the names of by using:

```
Import["file.shp", "LayerNames"]
```

I get something like

> {"Africover_Kenya_Spatial_Aggregation", "ke-landcover", "ke-forests", \
>   "ke-rangeland", "ke-agriculture", "ke-waterbodies", "ke-bareareas", \
>   "ke-urban", "ke-politicalboundary", "theme1"}

I would like to import just one layer ("ke-landcover" for example) from the data but I can't figure this out.

If I ask for the "Graphics" element, I think I get the layers individually, but I don't know how to verify whether this is true or not.  I'm new to mathematica, and documentation for GIS applications is limited at best.  Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: `Import["file.shp", "Elements"]` should tell you which elements are available for import. What does it say in your case?

Comment: {"Centering", "CentralScaleFactor", "CoordinateSystem", \
"CoordinateSystemInformation", "Data", "Datum", "Graphics", \
"GraphicsList", "GridOrigin", "InverseFlattening", "LayerNames", \
"LayerTypes", "LinearUnits", "Projection", "ProjectionName", \
"ReferenceModel", "SemimajorAxis", "SemiminorAxis", "SpatialRange", \
"StandardParallels"}

Comment: Extracting "LayerNames" returns

{"Africover_Kenya_Spatial_Aggregation", "ke-landcover", "ke-forests", \
"ke-rangeland", "ke-agriculture", "ke-waterbodies", "ke-bareareas", \
"ke-urban", "ke-politicalboundary", "theme1"}

and I want just the second element of the data that is contained in this second layer.

Comment: If I ask for the "Graphics" element, I think each layer is returned separately, but I'm not certain this is the case.  I do not know how to ascertain whether or not this is true.

Comment: Shapefiles do not have layers.  Perhaps you are importing an entire *directory* or archive of shapefiles (a "SHP bundle")?  In this case the layer names correspond to the individual shapefiles, which only have to be specifically named to be separately imported.

Comment: The shapefile has multiple attributes.  I'm trying to extract the data for one attribute, presumably identified with the "LayerNames" element.  There is only one file *.shp file in the bundle.

Comment: @whuber But `Import["file.shp", "LayerNames"]` is returning a list of layers for him...

Comment: @belisarius I cannot explain why that is. I agree with the OP that the documentation is (at best) incomplete--confusing is more like it--but I can reaffirm with great confidence my assertion about the lack of a "layer" structure in shapefiles. There is an authoritative, comprehensive specification available at http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf.  Possibly the OP did not actually use the command given in the question; possibly "file.shp" is actually the name of a directory! One clue is the appearance of "theme1": that's a temp shapefile dumped into the same directory.

Comment: @whuber http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8259576#8259576

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Import the data like:

```
dat = First@Import["/tmp/Archive.zip", "Data"];
```

A good start after importing a .shp file is to find out what data it contains:

```
dat /. Rule[a_, b_] :> a
(* {"LayerName", "Geometry", "Labels", "LabeledData"} *)
"Labels" /. dat
(* {"USERLABEL", "CODE1", "CODE2", "CODE3", "LCCCODE", "LCCLEVEL", "HECTARES", "LC"} *)
```

Let's group the geometry data by the LC label and see what we get:

```
labels = "LC" /. ("LabeledData" /. dat);
geometry = "Geometry" /. dat;
labeled = {labels, geometry}\[Transpose];
gathered = GatherBy[labeled, First@# &];

gathered//Length (* 6 *)
Union@labels (* {"AG", "BA", "NVT", "NVW", "UR", "WAT"} *)

g = Graphics[MapIndexed[
       {ColorData[1] @@ #2, Tooltip[#[[All, 2]], #[[1, 1]]]} &, gathered]
    ]
```

[image: kenya]

Using [this](http://www.africover.org/spatial_ke.htm) and some guessing the labels probably correspond to:

```
"AG"  Cultivated Terrestrial & Aquatic 
"BA"  Bare Areas
"NVT" Natural Vegetation - Terrestrial
"NVW" Natural Vegetation - Aquatic
"UR"
"WAT" Artificial & Natural Water
```

SHP files have a tendency towards completely cryptic labels

Comment: Nice spelunking

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!

Comment: @ssch where did you learn about how to tease apart the data like that?  Your solution was elegant, but I don't understand half of what you did.  Do you have any recommendations for resources?  Specifically I want to know about how to identify the different elements in an object and then how to interact with them individually like you did above.

Comment: @ShaunLangley I don't know any good resources :(  LabeledData is of the form `{"label1"->{"label1 for geometry[[1]]", "label1 for geometry[[2]]", ...}, "label2"->{"label2 for geometry[[1]]", "label2 for geometry[[2]]", ...}, ...}` So for instance the first element in geometry has the labels `("LabeledData" /. dat)[[All, 2, 1]]`

Answer (score 3):

At least here this seems to get the whole file, select the second element of the second layer and draw it:

```
Quiet@Graphics["Geometry" /. Import["c:\usamap.zip", "Data"][[2, 2]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Please note that the file is a zip bundle

**Edit: using your uploaded data file**

It has only one layer in it:

```
Import["c:\\Archive.zip", "LayerNames"]
(* "Africover_Kenya_Spatial_Aggregation" *)
```

It contains a map:

```
Import["c:\\Archive.zip"]
```

[image]

Comment: In my case, when I try and subset the element [[2,2]], it returns  

> Frame -> True

Comment: @ShaunLangley So your comment _"I want just the second element of the data that is contained in this second layer"_  seems misleading

Comment: I'm not sure how to phrase the question then. The data has multiple overlapping layers of data, identified with "LayerNames". I need to extract the data contained only in the second layer, but I don't know how to isolate that layer.

Comment: @ShaunLangley Is `Import["c:\usamap.zip", "Data"][[2]]` what you want?

Comment: No, I get the error "Part::partw: Part 2 of {{LayerName->Africover_Kenya_Spatial_Aggregation,<<2>>,LabeledData->{USERLABEL->{2H(CP)8,2TP28,2H(CP)8/2SV6,2SV6/2TC8,2SV6,2SV6,2SOJ67/2WC7,2SP6/4H(CP)F8,2SV6/2SOJ67,2H(CP)8/2SV6,2SP6,2H(CP)8/2SV6,2H(CP)8/2SV6,2SV6/2TC8,<<24>>,2H(CP)8/2SV6,2SV6,2SP6,2SV6,2SV6,2H(CP)8,8WN2,2H(CP)8/2SV6,2H(CP)8/2SV6,4WPF6,2H(CP)8/2SV6,2H(CP)8/6S,<<10498>>},<<6>>,LC-><<1>>}}} does not exist. >>

Comment: @ShaunLangley I guess it'll be easier if you upload your file somewhere

Comment: here is the [shapefile](https://www.box.com/s/a0as9elvw84bnd8f9zp2)

Comment: @ShaunLangley I only get "Africover_Kenya_Spatial_Aggregation" when importing "LayerNames" from that file (same from contained .shp)