# Graphics with shapefiles using tooltip

Tags: graphics, code-review, tooltip

I'm trying to write a code that displays an entire shapefile color-coded by one variable, and then as the mouse is moving it shows the local regional area of interest with all its data

Got a working code, but it doesn't seem efficient as I'm overlaying two different graphics, one with zero opacity. Is there a better way of implementing the code?

(Edit: Using Mathematica 9.0)

```
data = Import["http://exampledata.wolfram.com/usamap.zip", "Data"][[2]];
{Labels, BlockData} = Map[("LabeledData" /. data) /. Rule[a_, b_] :> # &, {a, b}];
ColorBy = "AREA";
Data4Color = ColorBy /. ("LabeledData" /. data);
Geometry = "Geometry" /. data;
labeled = {Data4Color, Geometry} // Transpose;
gathered = GatherBy[labeled, First@# &];
(* http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20207/8757 *)
InteractiveToolTip =
  Table[
    Tooltip[Geometry[[i]], {Graphics[Geometry[[i]]], 
    TableForm[{Labels, BlockData[[All, i]]} // Transpose]}], 
    {i, Dimensions[Geometry][[1]]}];  
h1 = MapIndexed[{ColorData[1] @@ #2, Tooltip[#[[All, 2]], #[[1, 1]]]} &, gathered];
Graphics[{h1, {Opacity[0], InteractiveToolTip}}, ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Trying to modify your code as little as possible:

```
{Labels, BlockData} = Map[("LabeledData" /. data) /. Rule[a_, b_] :> # &, {a, b}];
ColorBy = "AREA";
Data4Color = ColorBy /. ("LabeledData" /. data);
Geometry = "Geometry" /. data;
labeled = {Data4Color, Geometry, Transpose@BlockData}\[Transpose];
gathered = GatherBy[labeled, First@# &];
h1 = MapIndexed[{Tooltip[{ColorData[1] @@ #2, #[[All, 2]]}, 
                {Graphics@#[[All, 2]], TableForm[{Labels, Sequence @@ #[[All, 3]]} //Transpose]}]}&,
               gathered];
Graphics[h1, ImageSize -> Full]
```